# Is it better to develop on both mobile platforms in parallel or sequentially?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

We would like to develop an application that runs on both iOS and Android. We cannot come to a decision however whether it is better to first create the application on one platform and once we are satisfied, replicate it on the other, or finalize UX decisions in the beginning and develop the platforms in parallel.

The application is simple and we have the resources for developing it. It is just a question of whether to develop the platforms sequentially or in parallel and if sequentially, then which platform to start with (again assuming resource allocation is not an issue).

Comment: then don't forget to google about PhoneGap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had the very same debate when we started developing the app we're working on.

First, I should say that if your app is simple enough (doesn't have too many heavy animations, 3D, etc), you might want to look at some multi-platform solutions:
http://mobiledevices.about.com/od/mobileappbasics/tp/Top-5-Tools-Multi-Platform-Mobile-App-Development.htm

I personally feel that multi-platform solutions are still too far behind native apps, but it might be suitable for some apps.

In the end, we decided to develop the infrastructure of our app on one platform (Android), and then start building the app on the other platform (iOS), once the strength and performance of the Android app's infrastructure was proven. When we developed the iOS app, the infrastructure from the Android app was copied.

There are several advantages to this:

1. After you finish designing the architecture of the app, you test it once on one platform. If the architecture failed to hold up, you don't need to start 2 projects from scratch - only one.
2. Once you develop the app once, at least the infrastructure, you've already gone through all the major hurdles of development. This will allow you to complete the development of the other platform with relative ease and speed.
3. Developing 2 projects simultaneously will probably result in significant differences in the way the code works in both platforms. While there will always be some differences, due to the large differences between the platforms, it's better to minimize the difference between the way the apps operate - this will make maintaining the apps in the future much easier. (Solutions to problems will be essentially the same - iOS & Android teams can copy their solutions off each other).

Developing simultaneously will probably be quicker, but riskier, and will cost more time when you need to maintain your app.

Hope this helps your decision making :)

Answer (score 11):

As for me, developing both versions at the same time always means more time. You can have your design, workflow, architecture perfectly defined, but there'll always be changes during the development (not to say if there's an external client making decisions). If you're developing for both platforms in parallel, chances are that you will implement those changes twice, while if you first finish your app in one platform, you shouldn't find more unexpected surprises in the second one.

The next question then would be: *which platform should I start from?* I choose Android for two main reasons:

- It's a lot easier to refactor code / project structure (at least for me) in `eclipse` than `xcode`.
- I design the user interface keeping in mind the largest resolution (`Android xxhdpi`), then I cut my final png assets **once** using android resources naming conventions (which is more restrictive than ios), and run automated tasks for the rest of densities (`xhdpi`, `hdpi`, `mdpi`, `iOS` and `iOS@2x`)

---

Regarding cross-platform frameworks (i.e. phonegap), imho the effort will never be divided by two, and the user experience will never be close to the experience reached with a native application. Unless your app is *extremely simple*, I'd highly discourage these kind of frameworks.

Comment: Interesting point of view about cross-platform frameworks, thanks for sharing your opinion about.

Answer (score 0):

That depends strongly how you develop the app. If you develop on multi-plattform, I would suggest to us a framework like phonegap: http://phonegap.com/ . With this approach your question disappears and you saved half of the effort.

Answer (score 0):

If all resources are available and requirements are clear then you should go for parallel development because its not best practice to make any resource sit idle.